# How to redirect based on browser language using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've one italian site in the dir "www.example.com/it_IT" and one english site on "www.example.com/en_GB/"

I've tried to redirect the users based on browser locations. It works fine with index.php.

But it is not redirecting for complex urls such as "www.example.com/something/something" is not redirecting to 
"www.example.com/it_IT/something/something" if the browser language is italian or "www.example.com/en_GB/something/something" if the location is UK

---

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en_GB/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/it_IT/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: change this line RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en_GB/ [L,R=301] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/en_GB/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: also this RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/it_IT/ [L,R=301] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/it_IT/$1  [L,R=301]

Comment: clear browser cache then test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en_GB [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://example.com/en_GB/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !it_IT [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/it_IT/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: And if the client doesn't accept IT nor EN? What happen? Could we put a 'fallback' rule? Thanks a lot