# redirecting subdomain into get query string of another language .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm still struggling to figure out how exactly to redirect the user if somebody is calling my domain en.sparkm4n.de but is supposed to get [www.sparkm4n.de/index.php?lang=en](http://www.sparkm4n.de/index.php?lang=en) I want to keep the subdomain but I want that the script of .htaccess is exactly calling the php script which translates all the content inside of the subdomain. I have so far 3 subdomain like en.sparkm4n.de for english, fr.sparkm4n.de for french, es.sparkm4n.de for spanish and the top level domain which is www is german basically. I tried so far this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^en=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+)\.sparkm4n\.de$
RewriteRule ^(/?)$ $1?lang=%1en
```

I'm not quite certain if it does the right thing as I'm totally new to .htaccess regex.
What will be better solution to have 3 subdomains included in one .htaccess doing exactly fetching the content from toplevel get query into subdomain? There is no content inside of subfolder but it supposed to redirect to toplevel domain with all the content and scripts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect based on browser language using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985190/how-to-redirect-based-on-browser-language-using-htaccess)

Comment: As an alternative to dealing with htaccess, you can inspect `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the requested host and perform almost all of your logic in PHP.

Comment: the .htaccess redirect based on browser language is good for wordpress, Im using vanilla php. All the data is inside of top level domain. en, fr, es are created as subfolders but are empty. The logic of script should be to either fetch the data or redirect invisibly the user into top level domain while keeping the subdomain

Comment: And just to restate it, all that an "invisible redirect" does is parse the host header and append a query string to a specific location which you then read in PHP, and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` allows you to skip htaccess, and thus the invisible redirect and query string. It also makes your code portable across web servers and becomes much easier to test.

Comment: The solution with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] seems to work much better than .htaccess, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have it like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+)\.sparkm4n\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that this will rewrite every page with an additional `lang` parameter if it is missing. **This will not show `lang` parameter in browser URL** since we are not doing a full (external) redirect using `R` flag.

Comment: I changed this script but still it shows default page

Comment: For testing change flags to `[L,QSA,R]` and retest

Comment: I changed it but the default page still persists, I see the query string in the console but it doesnt seem to reach the top level domain

Comment: fr.sparkm4n.de is targeting subfolder which is empty but it is supposed to target the toplevel. because the logic is all in toplevel

Comment: Is `r.sparkm4n.de` a subdomain or not in Apache config?

Comment: fr.sparkm4n.de is a subdomain but hostinger created a subfolder automatically which is pointing to that

Comment: This will potentially rewrite _all_ requests, including static assets, not just "pages". So an additional filesystem check may be required.

Comment: @Sparkm4n "...but hostinger created a subfolder automatically which is pointing to that" - you would need to resolve this issue before implementing an `.htaccess` (or any?) solution. The subdomain should point to the same place as the main domain. There's no technical reason why it should point to a subdirectory, except if "Hostinger" is imposing this restriction.

Comment: @MrWhite: `additional filesystem check may be required`: Valid point, have added. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by using proposed `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`
Directly in the language script file I implemented this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  header('Cache-control: private');
  list($subdomain,$host) = explode('.', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
  if($subdomain == 'en'){
    $lang = 'en';
  } else if($subdomain == 'es'){
    $lang = 'es';
  } elseif($subdomain == 'fr'){
    $lang = 'fr';
  } else{
    $lang = 'de';
  }

  if(isSet($lang)){
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
  }
  else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
  }
  else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])){
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
  }
  else{
    $lang = 'de';
  }

  switch ($lang) {
    case 'en':
      $lang_file = 'en.php';
    break; 
    case 'fr':
      $lang_file = 'fr.php';
    break; 
    case 'es':
      $lang_file = 'es.php';
    break; 
    default:
    $lang_file = 'de.php';
  }
```

Comment: Just for reference, if you are on PHP 8 you can simplify your first condition to [this](https://3v4l.org/6iHTQ). Your second block that starts with `isSet($lang)` will always be true, the prior block guarantees that `$lang` is always set. For the third block, because you have already guarded the variable you don't necessarily need to test it again. You should be able to simplify everything down to https://3v4l.org/L3Lei